# Hide labels points in a FactoMineR PCA plot

Tags: r, plot, label

I did a PCA with FactoMineR package on data like this :

```
> data
      1  2  3  4  5
1000 15  4 14  6 13
1001 22 11 22 12 24
1002 15  7 19  9 10
1003 15  6 20 10 10
1004 12  3  5  4 11
1005 22 11 30 12 25
1006 13 12 24 25 21
1007 24 12 26  9 14
1008 21 11 24  7 18
1009 27  4 28 10 20
```

I then plot results like this :

```
C = as.factor(c(rep("one", 5), rep("two", 5)))
res = PCA(data, graph=F)
plot(res, col.ind=C)
```

[image]

I want to hide points labels and put a legend for each color, but I don't know how to. If someone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for that plotting function can be found at `?plot.PCA`. There is a parameter called `label=` that allows you to turn off labeling

```
plot(res, col.ind=C, label="none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, and do you know how to add a legends for each group of color ?